# Same style for image , but different border radius on Android

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, react-native-ios

The code

```
import { Image } from 'react-native';

<Image style={StyleSheet.flatten([styles.introPicSize, styles.introPicBorder])} source={require("../../assets/images/intro-pic.png")} />


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    introPicSize: {
        height: responsiveWidth(160),
        width: responsiveWidth(160),
        resizeMode:'contain'
    },
    introPicBorder: {
        borderWidth:8,
        borderRadius:100,
        borderColor:"#BDB9CD",
        overflow:'hidden'
    }
}
```

What expected is to have image with border radius 100 (circle) (On Android & IOS)

The result is fine for IOS

but for Android , it's a square not circle (it reads the borderRadius as 0 not 100

check the below image

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYimG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`borderRadius` does not work with `<Image />` in `Android`. You can see it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8885

The solution is to wrap it with the `View` and apply `borderRadius` for it.

```
<View style = {{flex: 1, borderRadius: 100}} >
    <Image style={ {width: 300, height: 100 } } source={{ uri: 'https://placekitten.com/300/100' }}> </Image> 
</View>
```